# Failing to read data from firestore using nextjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, array.prototype.map

I am trying to read data from firestore using getStaticprops on nextjs but instead, I am getting back an empty page. I have followed the docs on how to extract data using getStaticprops but for some reason, it is not working. This is how my code looks like

```
import React from 'react'
import { db } from '../firebase'
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const reference = collection(db, "students");

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(reference);
    const students = data.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}));

    return {
        props: {
           students
        }
    }
}

function Card({students = []}) {
    return (
        <div>
        <p>This is just a test</p>
        {students.map(student => (
            <h1>{student.surname}</h1>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Are there any error messages on the console?

Comment: @GabrielNexT no nothing just empty. Strange because I followed the docs exactly as they are

Answer (score 1):

After some analysis and tried sample code here are my understandings.

`getStaticProps` is used only for static site generation. ie. if your page always renders same data (which you are getting from api) then you can use getStaticProps.

For example, in your case you defined **Card** component with static props. This component will be having a route say `/Card`.

When you run `next build` the data will be obtained from server and used for that page. then `npm start`.  when you access `/Card` route, this data will be available.(note: getStaticProps will only be called in build time)

But if you call the same component from other pages,
then the static props will not be considered you have to provide your own props like

```
<Card students={[]} />
```

if you want to get student data whenever the page is rendered, then make the api call inside useEffect().

*Note: getStaticProps will only be called in build time thats why you were not getting any console.log() in console.It will be logged while building the site.*

Comment: Additionally, you can use `Incremental Static Regeneration` if the data in your component doesn't get updated that often. It offers best of SSR and SSG.
Reference Link: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: @Arjun thanks for the analysis. The thing is I am actively avoiding useEffect because they say it is not good for seo because I am trying to make a blog so having the site ranking is of most importance to me thats why I am having to try to force this getStaticProps thing. But if you were to pull data from firestore using nextjs, how would you write your code? I'm starting to think maybe a new approach is needed

Answer (score 0):

In firebase documentation examples, (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_6)

the response is used as array (data.forEach).But in your code you're accessing it like object (data.docs).

Can you try this,

```
const students = data.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}));
```

Comment: The issue persists still getting a blank page and nothing when I console log the students. Strange considering I am following the docs exactly as they are

Comment: did you console log the `data` ? what value it holds

Comment: its empty the console on the browser returns nothing. I am running the console log in the getStaticprops function right after I define the students.